# Custom List View off edge of screen

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridlayout

The build of my custom list row looks fine, but when I run the app the text fields on the right appear off the screen.  API 23.

Here is the listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.archerdx.fusionlibrary.FusionList">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fusionListView">
    </ListView>


</RelativeLay
```

out>

And here is the xml file of the custom rows I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/fusionName"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:textColor="#5987c6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Sources"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/sourceName"
        android:layout_weight="0.06"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#5987c6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Number of References"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/numberOfReferences"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#5987c6" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</GridLayout>
```

[image: Image of the text spilling off the screen]

Answer (score 1):

Give the width to your textviews `wrap_content`. Or if you want to show in single line the use this in your textviews:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using fixed layout widths, weights and a gridview which is never going to be a flexible solution.

Look in to using Linear or Relative layouts instead. There's plenty of info out there.